# Can I use the main power battery as a RTC battery as well?

Tags: batteries, pcb, rtc, nixie

Im currently thinking of a Nixie-Watch. Because I have almost no space on my PCB, I would like to use the 3.3v battery which powers the whole system also as the RTC Battery. I could connect a 3.3v voltage regulator if needed. What do you think about it? Could it work?

Comment: I didn't know they made nixie tubes small enough to wear as a watch on your wrist.

Comment: There are IN-17's. They are pretty small.

Comment: Why would you connect a 3.3 volt regulator to a 3.3 volt battery?

Comment: The voltage might drop

Comment: @Leocat then you'll need a very complex switch-mode supply to get it from say 3.2 V to 3.3 V and from 3.35 V to 3.3V, too. Is that really sensible? I don't know what you need as RTC supply, but you should check that first. Also, the nixie tubes not emptying the RTC battery would actually sound like a sensible feature.

Comment: I think this is getting very off topic. Can I use the main battery as a RTC battery or not?

Comment: Which RTC are you using?

Comment: Well I was thinking of using the DS1307 because it's rather popular.

Comment: DS1337 might be a better choice unless you need 5V for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the main battery as RTC battery so long as the voltage provided tp the RTC is suitable for RTC operation.

perhaps a schottky diode and a capacitor could help here.

Comment: Could you please explain it. How am I supposed to connect them?

Comment: use the capacitor to replace the RTC battery, and use the diode to prevent the main clock circuit from discharging the capacitor- it depends how you want to handle flat batteries and battery changes.

Comment: Thanks for the explination.